# How to get Type from antoher project of class of from class name string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

I need to get type of TestClass from AnotherProject.GetClassType method but I get null

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
namespace TestProject.MyClasses.Test
{

        public class TestClass
        {
          public void Print()
          {
            Console.Write("Hello World");
          }
        }
}
```

but I get type = null

I try this one  `Type type = Type.GetType("TestProject.MyClasses.Test.TestClass, TestProject");`

Comment: Have you tried to first load the assembly then [GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype) via the assembly?

Comment: You can also ask .NET to help you to construct the QualifiedName. [Assembly.CreateQualifiedName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.createqualifiedname)

Comment: @Tonikyan, Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following two methods to get type from another project.

**First Method**: we need to add the project as the reference in the current project.(Please right click->Add reference->Projects->Choose the project->Click OK)

Code:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("TestProject.TestClass, TestProject");
  Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
```

//Get the output TestProject.TestClass

**Second method**: We can use the absolute path to access the dll path.

```
            string dllname = "TestProject";
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName,dllname,"bin\\debug" ,dllname+".dll");
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path); 
            Type type = assembly.GetType("TestProject.TestClass"); 
            Console.WriteLine(type);
```

//Get the same result as the above

I define the Test class in the following code.

```
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```